# ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8

I've create a new website in IIS 8.5 to host classic asp page. I've choosen .net 4 as CLR framework and enabled classic mode.

I'm getting error "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server" when I try to fun website.

I believe ISAP & CGI restrictions are already available. Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 9):

1. Open IIS and click the server name.
2. Double click `ISAPI and CGI Restrictions`
3. Right click ASP.NET v4.0.30319 and select `allow`

Answer (score 7):

1. Open IIS.
2. Click this:

[image: click this]

3. Allow it.

[image: alow it]

4. Refresh your project on IIS

Answer (score 2):

Try

setting Managed **Pipeline Mode to Integrated**

instead of of Classic

Answer (score 1):

By default IIS 7 does not allow ISAPI and CGI through .Net 1.1. So if you are working with older code on IIS 7 you will need to follow these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Open IIS and click the server name
2. Double click “ISAPI and CGI Restrictions”
3. Right click ASP.NET v1.1 and select “allow”

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. You have to go to "Turn windows features on or off" and under the "Internet Information Services" choose "World Wide Web Services" then "Application Development Features" and you can turn them on there.

Edit: Names have been altered --- (The names might not be exactly the same the computer I am on has a German OS, I'll check once I am home and use the right ones.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable at the server level (not site level).

1. click the top level node. in iis
2. click 'isapi/cgi restrictions'
3. allow asp

Thats it.  I spent days before I noticed that my site had asp enabled but the server trumped the site setting.